# VNC with user queue

Tags: vnc

I'm searching for a VNC with a queue. Ie, when someone connect to a desktop and someone is already there, it would add him to a queue, warn the existing user and then, when he releases control, tell the next user in the queue that the computer is available.

Comment: As it stands this is a shopping question, which is against the site policies per the FAQ. Try rephrasing to fit the format.